# Install pdflatex via SSH on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, software-installation, amazon-ec2, latex

I need to install **pdflatex** on my Linux powered machine (Amazon EC2 instance, didn't decided yet which distribution would be the best so also feel free to give a hint) because I want to connect **pdflatex** & **PHP** to produce rendering of LaTeX code **to PDF** on my website (so user could type in LaTeX, click render and download a PDF, like http://www.scribtex.com). Can you give me some directions?

Comment: Did you build this system? Do you start a new pdflatex process each time you make changes?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your instance, you might already have a lot of `tex` tools installed. So when you get it, first check if they're there.

That being said, you can grab the `pdftex` source from the net using `wget`, and then compile it from there (assuming Amazon gives you compilers, I've never used their service). Something like this:

```
wget http://sarovar.org/frs/download.php/1292/pdftex-1.40.10.tar.bz2
tar xf pdftex-1.40.10.tar.bz2
cd pdftex-1.40-10
./configure
make
make install
```

Those commands will probably be different based on what kind of environment they give you. Just remember that you can download any file from the net using `wget` or `curl`. Once you've got that down, downloading source and packages is a breeze. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `texlive-pdftex` from any repository. For instance in current Amazon Linux (based on redhat) this appears:

```
$ yum search pdftex
Complementos cargados:priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
992 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
====================== N/S matched: pdftex ======================
texlive-pdftex-bin.x86_64 : Binaries for pdftex
texlive-pdftex-def.noarch : Colour and Graphics support for PDFTeX
texlive-pdftex-doc.noarch : Documentation for pdftex
texlive-iftex.noarch : Am I running under pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX?
texlive-pdftex.noarch : A TeX extension for direct creation of PDF
texlive-thumbpdf.noarch : Thumbnails for pdfTeX and dvips/ps2pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This question would possibly be on-topic on TeX Stack Exchange. If you are using Linux, you probably want to use TeX Live. Specifically, two reasonable choices are:

1) Use Debian (or Ubuntu) TeX Live packaging. The Debian TeX Packaging is quite good. It is also, mostly a one man effort, unfortunately, by [Norbert Preining](https://www.preining.info/).

2) Use upstream TeX Live. Norbert describes how do this [on Debian](http://tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

Answer (score 0):

The command I used recently to install pdflatex on an AWS instance for a similar application was:

`sudo yum install texlive-pdftex texlive-latex-bin texlive-texconfig* texlive-latex* texlive-metafont* texlive-cmap* texlive-ec texlive-fncychap* texlive-pdftex-def texlive-fancyhdr* texlive-titlesec* texlive-multirow texlive-framed* texlive-wrapfig* texlive-parskip* texlive-caption texlive-ifluatex* texlive-collection-fontsrecommended texlive-collection-latexrecommended`